# How to remove a parent and its children if child contains text

Tags: javascript, dom

I've searched through a number of similar issues, but can't seem to make this work.

Here's my HTML:

```html
 <div class="main">
    <p class="nameLink">name1</p>
    <p class="someClass"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <p class="nameLink">name2</p>
    <p class="someClass"></p>
  </div>
```

I would like to remove the div that contains a specific name, such as "name2".  HTML is currently being appended from a javascript file and the names are coming from a variable.

Here is what I've tried in javascript:

```js
var deleteName = "name2";
    $('.main p.nameLink').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == deleteName) {                    
          $('.main').has('p:contains(deleteName)').remove()
            return;
      }
    });
```

I just can't seem to remove the div containing the specific text.  Your help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove the parent with class "main" if the child contains text, or just the child with class "nameLink"?

Comment: @Damon, I would like to remove both the parent and the children if the children contain the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little bit overkill, you can use only selectors to remove it, no use to loop over it with a each(), unless you want to do specific actions with the p element:

```js
var deleteName = "name2";
$('.main').has('p.nameLink:contains(' + deleteName + ')').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <p class="nameLink">name1</p>
  <p class="someClass"></p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p class="nameLink">name2</p>
  <p class="someClass"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By including `deleteName` inside your single quotes, it's looking for a `p` that contains the literal text `"deleteName"`, not `"name2"`.

Try this:

```
var deleteName = "name2";
    $('.main p.nameLink').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == deleteName) {                    
          $('.main').has('p:contains(' + deleteName + ')').remove();
            return;
        }
});
```

---

Take a peak at what your code actually evaluates to (the commented portion):

**Your snippet:**

```
  $('.main').has('p:contains(deleteName)').remove()
//$('.main').has('p:contains(deleteName)').remove()
//Searching for text: deleteName
```

**Correction:**

```
  $('.main').has('p:contains(' + deleteName + ')').remove();
//$('.main').has('p:contains(name2)').remove();
//Searching for text: name2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to interpolate the `deleteName` variable. Currently as it is, you're checking any paragraph tag that contains the text `deleteName` and instead of passing through the value `name2`.

You need to use string concatenation. For example: `'string ' + 1 + ' something'`, yields `'string 1 something'`.

Here's your code working:

```js
var deleteName = "name2";
$('.main p.nameLink').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == deleteName) {
    $('.main').has('p:contains(' + deleteName + ')').remove()
    return;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <p class="nameLink">name1</p>
  <p class="someClass"></p>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p class="nameLink">name2</p>
  <p class="someClass"></p>
</div>
```